# How do I verify that my transactions w. Mongoose are handling errors/roll-backs correctly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, transactions

I'm trying to learn how to implement transactions for a simple app in Mongoose with express for a RESTful API.

I've managed to put together a small one change function using the mongoDB session.withTransaction() helper function.
This code block runs with no errors and the document appears in the DB as I would expect.

```
function createCourse() {
  try {
    return Course.createCollection()
      .then(() => mongoose.startSession())
      .then(session => {
        session.withTransaction(() => {
          return Course.create(
            [
              {
                author: "Larry",
                category: "web",
                tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
                isPublished: false,
                price: 15,
                name: "Tester series 3"
              }
            ],
            { session }
          );
        });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something with how to structure my operations with this function.
Putting everything together into an Express POST method, looks like this works but I'd appreciate a code-review of it.

Also, how can I go about testing that the code is correctly handling errors/roll-backs? Put session.abortTransaction(); somewhere within the sesson.withTransaction() block?

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    validateRental(req.body);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let customer = null;
  try {
    customer = await Customers.findById(req.body.customerId);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid customer.");
  }

  let movie = null;
  try {
    movie = await Movies.findById(req.body.movieId);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid movie.");
  }

  if (movie.numberInStock === 0)
    return res.status(400).send("Movie not in stock.");

  try {
    mongoose.startSession().then(session => {
      session.withTransaction(async () => {
        let rental = new Rentals({
          renter: {
            _id: customer._id,
            name: customer.name,
            phone: customer.phone,
            isGold: customer.isGold
          },
          movie: {
            _id: movie._id,
            title: movie.title,
            dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate
          }
        });

        await rental.save({ session });
        movie.numberInStock--;
        await movie.save({ session });
        res.send(rental);
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});
```